# mongoose difference between .create and .save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I did a bootcamp on udemy long back on Express and Mongoose where suppose we want to add new field in data, we did something like this

```
var playground = require("../models/playground.js");

route.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn,function (req, res) {

  var name =  req.body.name;
  var image =  req.body.image;
  var description = req.body.description;
  var price = req.body.price;

  playground.create({
    name: name,
    image:image,
    description: description,
    price: price
  }, function(error, newlyCreated){
    if(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    else {
      newlyCreated.author.id = req.user._id;
      newlyCreated.author.username = req.user.username;
      newlyCreated.save();
     res.redirect("/playground");
    }
  })
});
```

Now, it's been about more than year and I am unable to comprehend what I am doing here (should have added some comments) but I do see we are using something like this `playground.create({`

and then there is this here which I completely unable to comprehend

```
          newlyCreated.author.id = req.user._id;
          newlyCreated.author.username = req.user.username;
          newlyCreated.save();
```

This isn't a primary question but what will `newlyCreated.save();` will do? I mean it would probably save the data we are getting from the front end but how will it work?

Moving on to the primary question, I was again following a tutorial where the instructor did something as simple as this to save data

```
 let author = new Author({  
     name: args.name, 
     age: args.age
       })
 author.save()
```

So what is in general difference between `.create` and `.save`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose save vs insert vs create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290684/mongoose-save-vs-insert-vs-create)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `Model.create()` is a shortcut for saving one or more documents to the
>   database.
>
> `MyModel.create(docs)` does `new MyModel(doc).save()` for every doc in
>   docs.
>
> This function triggers the following middleware.
>
> - save()

---

Reference:https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create

Comment: Were you able to make sense of this?  `newlyCreated.author.id = req.user._id;
          newlyCreated.author.username = req.user.username;
          newlyCreated.save();` Because In the above if I did something like this ` playground.create({` then why did we do something like this `newlyCreated.save()`? Also thanks a lot for asking :)

Answer (score 2):

.save() and .create() both does the same work.
The important difference is that .save() **bypasses schema validation** but .create() checks if the data conforms the schema and then it will trigger the .save() method internally

Comment: I don't think so, save is used on the instance of the model whereas create is used on the model itself and uses save internally. Both of them checks schema validation.

Answer (score 0):

Read **Constructing Documents** section. **.save()** and **.create()** are just different ways to add documents to the collection.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

```
const Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
small.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});

// or

Tank.create({ size: 'small' }, function (err, small) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});

// or, for inserting large batches of documents
Tank.insertMany([{ size: 'small' }], function(err) {

});
```

Comment: I donot remember where i learned this but , .save() directly saves the document into the DB without verifying the schema whereas .create will first check if the data to be saved is valid according to schema and then only it will trigger .save() method .

Comment: You are saying .save() skips the schema verification I don't think that is true. Because most of the time I use .save() to save the document in the DB. and whenever I try to add something that is against my schema I do get errors.  The .save() is an instance method of the model, while the .create() is called directly from the Model as a method call, being static in nature, and takes the object as a first parameter.